# White pink leaves of Adenium? Albino?

Tags: leaves, seedlings

I sow some Adenium seeds few weeks ago.. some were germinated and looking really very good. But one plant have pink and white leaves.. initially I thought this is some kind of disease and new leaves will grow with green color. But I was wrong new leaves are also pink white..

Is it something like albino? because I have never heard of anything like plants are also albino.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you have a suitable stock, you could graft this onto it. The white seedling probably won't survive without intervention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not albino, but variegated. There are varieties of Adenium which have variegated leaves, some of which have pink edges or pink tints, others have yellow variegation or whitish yellow. Sounds like you just happen to have a seed germinated which is from a variegated variety.

UPDATE: I see you've added pictures - that 'seedling' (showing white with a pink tinge) which is growing looks like a case of mutation/fasciation/proliferation. At the very least, it seems to be lacking chlorophyll, so maybe there's an issue with its chloroplasts. You'll have to wait and see what happens with it, it almost looks like a flower... I'll be interested to see more pics of its progress. And yes, 'albino' would be a good word to use at this stage.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. And sure I'll post some more images as it grow.

Comment: If the chlorophyll is lacking, it may become parasitic using the nutrients via the roots of the same type of plant to survive. [Albino Redwood Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albino_redwood)